# /var/lib/mysql grows indefinitely in size

Tags: mysql, size, upgrade

Having the need to upgrade from Ubuntu Bionic to Ubuntu Focal, I made an upgrade from server 5.7 - deduced afterwards - to 8.0 by simply inheriting the original /var/lib/mysql directory, that is I left those files where they were (after making a backup of that directory). To get rid of some incompatibility found in the original configuration file (my.cnf) I purged everything of the old package and started the new 8 server with the configuration shipped with its package.

Apparently the server was working fine, that is I didn't find any particular complain in /var/log/mysql/error.log and websites were finding their expected data.

But after a few days I found the disk space was totally or almost exhausted. I freed some space and noticed /var/lib/mysql has grown from about 38G to more than 100G (I issued the command du -sh * in /var/lib), and was still growing.

What did I wrong? Perhaps I made a big mistake in upgrading the server in the way I mentioned?

I tried to restore the original /var/lib/mysql and start the server again, but it grows in size anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

**--- UPDATE ---**
It turned out in versions older than MySQL 8.0 binary logging was disabled by default. This was no more the case. I workarounded with `skip-log-bin` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` (the OS is an Ubuntu Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else knows an in-place fix. My solution is to back up and restore as outlined [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-back-up-and-restore-mysql-databases-with-mysqldump/):

```
# du -sh /var/lib/mysql
141G    mysql/
# mysqldump -u root --password=password database_name > database_name.sql
# du -sh database_name.sql
62M     database_name.sql
# mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
# mkdir /var/lib/mysql
# mysql -u root --password=password -e "create database database_name"
# mysql -u root --password=password database_name < database_name.sql
# du -sh /var/lib/mysql/
402M    mysql/
```

Of course, replace database_name and its username/password credentials with your setup. When satisfied that your data has all been restored then go ahead and delete `/var/lib/mysql.old`.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. Though apparently the problem I faced was not related to the data. Please read the update above.